# SQL SUM Returns wrong result

Tags: sql, vb.net, t-sql

Hello I am trying to get the right SUM from my query, and i know that this works:

```
SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) From IncomingInvoiceLine inner Join [File] ON IncomingInvoiceLine.FILENUMBER = [File].FILENUMBER WHERE [File].RELATIONCODE = '12TU01'
```

But this is the amount without the currency being calculated so i tried this:

```
    SELECT fmsTotalAmountIncoming INTO TempIncomingAmounts FROM (
        SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN fms1.currency != 'EUR'
            THEN fms1.amount * fms1.rate
        ELSE ISNULL(fms1.amount, 0) END ) fmsTotalAmountIncoming
    FROM [fms].[dbo].[IncomingInvoiceLine] fms1
    WHERE fms1.RELATIONCODE = '12TU01'
    ) a 

    SELECT fmsTotalAmountIncoming FROM [fms].[dbo].[TempIncomingAmounts]

    DROP TABLE [fms].[dbo].[TempIncomingAmounts]
```

And this does not return the right result, it returns NULL while the first query returns:

> 8145.46

Yet I can't figure out why the query with the currency being converted returns NULL. It should return

> 8106.546

(I first made this in vb.net and then wanted to make it faster by writing a stored procedure).

Does anyone see why it does this?

Comment: Try doing a null check on the multiplication: `ISNULL(fms1.amount * fms1.rate, 0)`.

Comment: This does not make a difference. The relationcode 123K01 should return 0, and returns 4927.16, I have no clue where this number comes from.

Comment: Then remove the sum, and return all values, so you can be sure you are comparing like for like.. you should also then find a value of 38.914 :)

Comment: in the second query did you skip the INNER JOIN [FILE] on purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in the end was my stupidity, i was trying to get it directly from the IncomingInvoiceLine, while i needed to inner join on file. Now it works, using this:

```
SELECT fmsTotalAmountIncoming INTO TempIncomingAmounts FROM (
    SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN fms1.currency != 'EUR'
        THEN fms1.amount * fms1.rate
    ELSE ISNULL(fms1.amount, 0) END) fmsTotalAmountIncoming
FROM [fms].[dbo].[file] f
    INNER JOIN [fms].[dbo].[incominginvoiceline] fms1 ON 
    fms1.filenumber = CONVERT(NVARCHAR, f.filenumber)
    WHERE f.RELATIONCODE = @RelationCode
) a
```

Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

I Think your multiplication may causing the problem. Because i have tried the same problem with some dummy data and it is giving the the accurate result means it is not giving any null value

```
 SELECT fmsTotalAmountIncoming INTO TempIncomingAmounts FROM (
    SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN fms1.currency != 'EUR'
        THEN fms1.amount * 0.5
    ELSE ISNULL(fms1.amount, 0) END ) fmsTotalAmountIncoming
FROM [fms].[dbo].[IncomingInvoiceLine] fms1
WHERE fms1.RELATIONCODE = '12TU01'
) a 

SELECT fmsTotalAmountIncoming FROM [fms].[dbo].[TempIncomingAmounts]

DROP TABLE [fms].[dbo].[TempIncomingAmounts]
```

If the above query results the correct result then its the multipilcation problem.

Comment: I have found the problem. It was because our database is so big it sometimes gets unreadable to my eyes. It was the wrong table :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because our fms1.amount * fms1.rate.

Rate is informat X.XX, cast it to the same format as `amount`.

It can be conversely. Add more info (data type of amount and data type of rate) for more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

may be one of the null value  in multiplication.
You can figure out following way

ISNULL(fms1.amount * fms1.rate, 0)